# C# split array in groups of 30 then call api

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, loops

I would like to ask for help with a loop.

My method receives a JSON string with names and email addresses, it uses this string of objects to pass to an external API POST request.

I just found out that the API can process only 30 items at a time otherwise it does not validate.

I would like to learn how to check if the json string contains more than 30 items, if it does, then process 30 items at a time when calling the api. Is it possible to get a sample of how this loop would need to be?

My method currently does these steps:

```
public ActionResult CreatePanelists(Parameters data)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var webId = data.webId;
    var jwt_token = JWTToken.GetJWTToken();
    var panelists = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.panelists);   <- this is the array
    var client = new RestClient($"https://api/{webId}/panelists");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {jwt_token}");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", $"{{\"panelists\": {panelists}}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = response.StatusCode, message = response.Content} };

}
```

Any help would be awesome.

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

I added the example code, and seeing a few errors:

```
'index': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter

Syntax error, '=>' expected

Invalid expression term ')'

'item': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter
```

**UPDATE2**

The returns part is complaining now, response is within the loop and not accessible to the return

```
The name response does not exists in the current context.

return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = response.StatusCode, message = response.Content} };
```

**UPDATE3**

```
public ActionResult CreatePanelists(Parameters data)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var results = new List<string>();
    var webId = data.webId;
    var jwt_token = JWTToken.GetJWTToken();
    
    var batches = data.panelists
        .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
        .GroupBy(t => t.index / 30)
        .Select(g => g.Select(t => t.item))
        .Select(batch => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batch));

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var client = new RestClient($"https://api/meetings/{webId}/panelists");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {jwt_token}");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", $"{{\"panelists\": {batch}}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        
        results.AddItem(JSON);
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = results };
```

AddItem:

```
    public static void AddItem<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        if (!list.Contains(item))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

If you have any suggestions as to how to make the code better, please let me know

Comment: You say you have code that receives a JSON string. But you have posted code that creates a JSON string. Which is it? Are you simply asking how to check `data.panelists` for the number of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ for example:

```
var batches = data.panelists
    .Select((item, index) => (item, index))
    .GroupBy(t => t.index/30)
    .Select(g => g.Select(t => t.item))
    .Select(batch => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batch));

foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {jwt_token}");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", $"{{\"panelists\": {batch}}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); // somehow process/join the result
}
```

Comment: Hello @Guru Stron - I added your example, and I get a few errors: 
'index': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter
Syntax error, '=>' expected
Invalid expression term ')'
'item': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter

Comment: @erasmocarlos what version of C# are you using? It [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rn2r9Q) for me. Try changing first select to `.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})`. And try renaming `item` and `index` into something else.

Comment: I am using VS 2015 .NET Framework 4.5.2 - let me try what you recommended, and report back.

Comment: would you please look at my mos recent update? I am getting a new error

Comment: @erasmocarlos yes, that's why I have comment `somehow process/join the result` in my code.

Comment: that is a bummer, I am not sure how to accomplish that

Comment: @erasmocarlos it depends on your business logic. Can't decide it for you.

Comment: I need to be able to send the response string to the front end of the angularjs application, but not sure how to join multiple responses now that the execution is within a loop.

Comment: @erasmocarlos it depends on what is actually in the responses. Also it depends on how you want to handle failures.

Comment: I am trying to still figure this out. trying to handle multiple responses by adding them to a list and then returning the list contents, but it is quite messy. I posted what I have so far under UPDATE3, If you have any suggestions as to how to make the code better, please let me know.

Comment: @erasmocarlos Looks fine to me, TBH. Also you can use [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) instead of list and you will not need your custom `AddItem` method. And not sure if you actually need whole response serialized(also you can just add them to the list and process them later).

Comment: let me see if I can figure this out. Thank you.